# Setup a scanner from command line or ARD

Tags: command-line, remote-desktop, scanning

I know how to add a networked printer via the command line or ARD (Apple Remote Desktop); and, I know how to install the TWAIN scanner drivers for a particular vendor (again, using ARD).

But, what I'm wondering is if there is a way to setup a scanner (so that the "Print & Scan" preference pane is aware of it) without interactively going through the system prefs for every computer.

We have an multifunction printer/scanner/fax that I'd love to be able to set up this way, but so far, I can't find any solutions.

(Edit)
When adding a multifunction printer via system prefs, the scanner is only added if you let Bonjour form the connection.  If you set the IP of the printer directly, then the Scan option will not be seen in the pref pane for the printer.  The Bonjour method is not good for us, because the computers are eventually connected to various subnets, and MDNS is blocked between the subnets.

So, if there is a way to add the scanner via its IP, it will allow us to setup the device once for all computers, and not care about which subnet it might eventually end up connected to...

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't found an answer to the exact problem, I *do* have a workaround (I think).

If you add the multi-function printer via the System Preferences, you can use CUPS to change the settings of that printer.

Turn on the web interface:

```
cupsctl WebInterface=yes
```

Go to localhost:631/ in your favorite web browser, select "Printers" at the top, and select the recently-added printer in the list.

There will be two pull-down selectors, defaulting to `Maintenance` and `Administration`.  On the administration one, change it to `Modify Printer`.  You'll need to enter the computer administrator username/password at this point.

The first screen will show the current connection as what it was set to by bonjour (dnssd://.....) , along with a list of other options.  Near the bottom, in the "Other Network Printers" section, select `LPD/PLPR Host or Printer` and press Continue.

Update the Description and Location if necessary, on the next screen.  You can also update the driver; however, the default driver is probably adequate.

Now, instead of polling the bonjour/mdns name for the printer, it connects directly to the IP.  Printers can be accessed from any spot on the network; but, scanning functions only work from the same subnet.

This doesn't help set up a mass-deployment; but, it would allow you to make a net-install image, and push that entire image to the other computers.  That is what we'll end up doing here for the time being; until I can figure out what settings are being saved that indicate a particular printer has scan capabilities.